# How to run hdp3.1?

Tags: hadoop, docker-compose, hortonworks-sandbox, hdp

I'm newer in Big data solution developments.
To have a complete environment I decide to install hdp 3.1 docker image.
After installation, I taped this two commands like mentioned in this installation guide: https://www.cloudera.com/tutorials/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/3/.html

docker start sandbox-hdf
docker start sandbox-proxy
Now after doing this , I don't know what doing in the next step, I don't found any indication of URL address for starting my real work, I don't fount what are the settings that I must do it before starting. Please, anyone has an experience with hdp 3.1 can help me. Thank you a lot.

https://www.cloudera.com/tutorials/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/3/.html

Comment: could i see your snadbox-hdf docker's screenshot

Comment: this is how it's look ![snadbox-hdf docker's screenshot](https://ibb.co/xLpHkGR).

Comment: You can type "localhost:8080" on your chrome to launch hdp manager, and 8088 for resource manager , 50070 for Namenode manager